# How can I add a custom toolbar button to Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, add-in

How can I add a simple toolbar button to IE that gets the current url and redirect to another url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Powering up with Internet Explorer Extensibility](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/09/06/461675.aspx)
- [Adding Toolbar Buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588.aspx) at MSDN

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to get deep into all the IE extension stuff, you could go with a bookmarklet and just use javascript to get the same behaviour you are looking for:

```
javascript:if(location.href="http://www.google.com"){ location.href="http://www.yahoo.com"}
```

This also has the advantage working on many different browsers.

[Bookmarklet Info](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/ie/bookmarklets.htm)